# (In Real Analysis) Proving that the inverse of the composition of two functions is the composition of the inverses of said functions, order reveresed

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm reading introduction-to-real-analysis-4th-ed-r-bartle-d-sherbert-wiley-2011-ww, and in chapter 1, 1.1.14 there's a theorem that I've been trying to prove: [image: On the relationship between composite functions and inverse images. f is a function from set A into set B, and g is a function from set B into set C, and H is a subset of C. (g∘f)^(-1)(H)=f^(-1)(g^(-1)(H))]

All I have for inverse images is:"Let *f* be a function from set A to set B" "If *H* is a subset of *B*, then the **inverse image** of *H* under *f* is the subset *f*^-1 (*H*) of *A* given by *f*^-1(*H*):={x ϵ A : *f*(x) ϵ *H*}" and that *f*(*f*^-1(*H*)) is not automatically H (I'm not assuming the functions f and g have inverse functions, because it doesn't specify that they are bijective). I'm stumped, there's something about the mixing of composite functions and inverse images I'm not getting: if someone could shed light on this, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Keep track of the preimage at every step. You will need to use that $f$ and $g$ are functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just carefully apply the definition of inverse image that you have written at the end of your question.

- If $x \in (g \circ f)^{-1}(H)$, then $g(f(x)) \in H$. (Why?)
- Then $f(x) \in g^{-1}(H)$. (Why?)
- Then $x \in f^{-1}(g^{-1}(H))$. (Why?)
- Therefore, $(g \circ f)^{-1}(H) \subseteq f^{-1}(g^{-1}(H))$.

Use a similar argument to show the reverse inclusion $(g \circ f)^{-1}(H) \supseteq f^{-1}(g^{-1}(H))$.

Comment: ah, that first step is what I was needing. I don't know why I wasn't seeing it. Thank you so much